# Handling Grammar / Spelling Issues in Translation Strings

Tags: variables, internationalization, translation, grammar, spelling

We are currently implementing a Zend Framework Project, that needs to be translated in 6 different languages. We already have a pretty sophisticated translation system, based on Zend_Translate, which also handles variables in translation keys.

Our project has a new Turkish translator, and we are facing a new issue: Grammar, especially Turkish one. I noticed that this problem might be evident in every translation system and in most languages, so I posted a question here.

Question: Any ideas how to handle translations like:

```
Key: I have a[n] {fruit} 
Variables: apple, banana
Result: I have an apple. I have a banana.
Key: Stimme für {user}[s] Einsendung
Variables: Paul, Markus
Result: Stimme für Pauls Einsendung,
Result: Stimme für Markus Einsendung
```

Anybody has a solution or idea for this? My only guess would be to avoid this by not using translations where these issues occur.
How do other platforms handle this?

Of course the translation system has no idea which type of word it is placing where in which type of Sentence. It only does some string replacements...

PS: Turkish is even more complicated:

```
For example, on a profile page, we have "Annie's Network". This should translate as "Annie'nin Aği".
If the first name ends in a vowel, the suffix will start with an n and look like "Annie'nin"
If the first name ends in a consonant, it will not have the first n, and look like "Kris'in"
If the last vowel is an a or ı, it will look like "Dan'ın"; or Seyma'nın"
If the last vowel is an o or u, it will look like "Davud'un"; or "Burcu'nun"
If the last vowel is an e or i, it will look like "Erin'in"; or "Efe'nin"
If the last vowel is an ö or ü, it will look like "Göz'ün'; or "Iminönü'nün"
If the last letter is a k (like the name "Basak"), it will look like "Basağın"; or "Eriğin"
```

Comment: Why do you say _pretty sophisticated Translation System_? I don't understand, sorry. The examples from English and German are very basic (no declination) and your systems is not managing those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually very hard problem, as grammar rules are different even among languages from the same family. I don't think you could easily do anything for let's say Slavic languages...

However, if you want to solve this problem (because this is extra challenging) and you are looking for creative (cross inspiring) ways to do that, you might want to look into something called ChoiceFormat (example would be one from [ICU Project](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classChoiceFormat.html)) or you can look up [GNU Gettext's solution for plural forms problem](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#Translating-plural-forms).

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. The Translation Solution we currently have could handle plurals. But it is not only about plurals ... it seems more complicated...

Comment: I know it is not only about plurals, and what you actually wanted was something that is called Inflection. I gave you some examples of other linguistic problems and the way to resolve them. If I were to implement solution for Inflection, I would probably go for combination of Regular Expressions, Choice Formatter and translator provided metadata. It is very hard problem, really.

Answer (score 1):

ICU (mentioned above) has a SelectFormat http://site.icu-project.org/design/formatting/select that may be of help- it's like a choice format but with arbitrary keywords.  Also, it does have a PluralFormat which already has rules for many language's plural rules.